Acer tree not thriving - UK
I bought a three foot acer tree last year. Over the winter it was kept inside a greenhouse for protection from the wind and frost. The tree was fine and in spring I bought it out and it blossomed. The tree has not had any new growth in the last couple of months and some of the leaves have started shrivelling up and I'm concerned there may be something wrong. I water it when the top soil is starting to not feel as moist. It's in a pot with free draining soil inside a bigger pot that also has a drainage hole. I've also used some liquid fertiliser this last week.
Would be great to have some advice on what you think the problem is and how to remedy it.
Thanks guys

Need more info please. How big is the pot that contains the tree's roots? Is there soil in the large pot it sits in? What variety of Acer is it? Where has it been standing, in sun, shade or an exposed and windy situation? Lastly, a photo would be helpful...
